# Prolog Recursion might not be exiting with proper boundary condition

Tags: recursion, prolog, logic-programming

Given the following database:

```
location(desk, office).
location(apple, kitchen).
location(flashlight, desk).
location('washing machine', cellar).
location(nani, 'washing machine').
location(broccoli, kitchen).
location(crackers, kitchen).
location(computer, office).
location(envelope, desk).
location(stamp, envelope).
location(key, envelope).

is_contained_in(X, Y) :-
    location(Z, Y),
    is_contained_in(X, Z).
```

I expect the following query

```
is_contained_in(Y, kitchen).
```

to yield all the items are inside the kitchen. Instead, all the output I get is `false`. Furthermore, I expect my query to yield me a list of all the items that exist inside the kitchen regardless of whether or not they are inside other items.

Why is the the is_contained_in predicate not giving me the desired result with the query

```
is_contained_in(Y, kitchen).
```

Comment: Just because you write wrong predicate. Right will look like 
```is_contained_in(X, Y) :- location(X,Y).
is_contained_in(X, Y) :- location(X,Z), is_contained_in(Z,Y).
```

Comment: Here is swi-prolog notebook:
https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/iYTNVBiL.swinb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `is_contained_in(X, Y)` does not have a condition to match when `X` is directly located in `Y`, and because any containment relation will eventually require direct location to match, it won't find anything. You need an extra clause to handle that case:

```
is_contained_in(X, Y) :- location(X, Y).
```

Comment: You all answered it pretty well, but I think this is the official answer. There was a good explanation too. Thank you.